# SQL postgres - comma issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have data that looks similar to

```
     DBA PITSTOP #4365 XXX AK FAIRXXX
```

There is some variation within the rows (over 2mill). I need simply the number from the rows, which I used

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING('DBA PITSTOP #4365 XXX AK FAIRXXX', 'P #*([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]{1,4})')
```

Which returns

```
    4365
```

As desired. However, in the cases where there is a , and not a 4 digit code (i.e. 4, or 43, or 436, ) the comma gets returned as well. I can't seem to figure out how to get around it. 
I needed to use the P # to avoid any instances where the data started with an integer, and the number varies from 1 to 4 digits. Its just that darn comma.

Thanks!

Comment: `'P #*([0123456789]{1,4})'` or simply `'P #*([\d]{1,4})'`

Comment: thank you! that worked. darn commas.